# This model adapter does not support fetching records from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, cancancan

After upgrading my application from rails 5.2 to rails 6 and I am getting this issue

**This model adapter does not support fetching records from the database.**

```
class PlayerArtController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource only: [:index, :create]

  def index
     
  end

  def create
  end

end
```

Version:

rails (6.0.3.4)
cancancan (2.3.0)
ruby 2.7.2

Comment: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/556

Comment: This link I have already seen but I don't want to update my cancancan. I was looking for a workaround

Comment: I think you will find updating cancancan is the quickest and most reliable route to resolving the issue.

Comment: Why would you not upgrade? What is blocking you from doing so? Cancancan 2 does not support Rails 6.

Comment: @coorasse I thought just for a one bug I can apply a patch since my application is a big monolith

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by @Eyeslandic I ended up updating cancancan from 2.3 to 3.0

Answer (score 2):

```
CanCan::NotImplemented (This model adapter does not support fetching records from the database.):
```

Records were not fecthed from database, after updating the gem resolved the issue:

```
# gem 'cancancan', '2.3.0'  ## update version to new version
gem 'cancancan', '~> 3.3.0'
```